# setState method causes infinite loop of Results in Reactjs Functions

Tags: reactjs

The code displays users records from an array.
I also creates an `updateCount()` function which counts users on content display.

I can see the count results **alerted** and in the console.

Now I want to display the count results and to this effect, I initialize `setState()` method within the `updateCount` function.

```js
updateCount = userId => {
    ...some code missing
    this.setState({dataCount: count});
}
```

This causes infinite loop of the results due to re-rendering.
Is there anyway to get the `setState` out of the `UpdateCount()` function to enable me display the count results well or any better possible approach.

**Here is the Code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      userCount: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var userId = "100";

    this.setState({
      data: [
        {
          id: "100",
          name: "Luke"
        },
        {
          id: "200",
          name: "Henry"
        },
        {
          id: "300",
          name: "Mark"
        }
      ]
    });

    this.updateCount = this.updateCount.bind(this);
  }

  updateCount = userId => {
    var count = 1;
    alert("counting: " + count);
    console.log("counting: " + count);

    this.setState({ dataCount: count });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          (---{this.state.dataCount}--)
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => {
              if (person.id == 100) {
                //this.updateCount(person.id);

                return (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <div>
                      {person.id}: {person.name}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              } else {
                this.updateCount(person.id);
              }
            })}
          </ul>{" "}
        </label>{" "}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: State updates shouldn't occur in `render` exactly for this reason. *updateCount() function which counts users on content display* - why should it be updated on content display and not earlier?

Comment: you should do this check in getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render):

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

Since `updateCount()` is calling `setState()`, you are calling `setState` in `render`. You need to redesign your code code, possibly creating array in `state` and using `map` in render.

Using [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) might be a good idea, make sure you to use a conditional statement, else you might hit another infinite loop.

Answer (score 8):

You are calling in your `render()` method `this.updateCount(person.id)` which do a `setState`. Therefore a re-rendering occurs, and then `this.updateCount(person.id)` is called again. And it goes on.. (infinite loop)

Comment: Sir Samb102 I guess that as well. But am still struggling to figure out away to get it working